# Subtract two dates in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know, if the difference between two dates is one day. What I mean by 1 day is that let's say if I have a PreviousDate as '03/19/2014 11:59:59 PM' and CurrentDate as '03/20/2014 12:00:00 AM'. I still want the answer as 1 day, even if the difference is just 60 seconds. I am using Oracle 10g.
Currently I am doing like this and it is returns me 0 as i think it is rounding the fraction value.

```
Select CAST((CurrentDate - PreviousDate) AS NUMBER(10,0)) from TempTable;
```

Comment: thanks everyone for quick response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select trunc(CurrentDate )-trunc(PreviousDate) from TempTable;
```